# Using PSD templates in android

Tags: android

I found a lot of free templates in PSD format for android [here](http://speckyboy.com/2014/01/15/50-best-web-mobile-gui-templates-2013/). How do we actually incorporate these templates into our applications? Could I have some pointers?

Comment: You can't use PSD graphics in Android. You have to convert them to a supported graphic format. Just use the icons, backgrounds and colors and replicate the layouts in xml (add some fantasy and change the color schemes, too). Save the graphics at proper sizes and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are used by and large for mocking layouts. Generally you have to build the layouts in XML by hand using a composition of existing widgets, bitmaps and drawables.

So you would need to create or extract the bitmaps you want from the PSD templates and incorporate these.

As I said though, a lot of templates are just used for mocking designs, and you might not find them easy to slice and dice.